# Displaying Steps for a Babylonian Root

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, sqrt

So I have all of the code set up to where it'll give me the square root and I have the user input of the initial number you want the square root of and the user input for a guess.

I need to use a while loop to display how many steps it will take to get to the square root of the number and display "it took (however many steps) to get the square root of (user input value) to be (sqrt)"

Format:

```
Enter a number: 72
Enter a starting guess: 36
The square root of 72.000000 is 8.485281

step 1: 19.000000
step 2: 11.394737
step 3: 8.856722
step 4: 8.493070
step 5: 8.485285
step 6: 8.485281
Using the Babylonian method, the square root of 72
with a starting guess of 36 was found in 6 steps.
```

Also included was this guessing formula, but I don't understand what it is used for:

```
guessk+1 = ½(guessk + (N/guessk))
```

So far, my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

        double N;
        double guess;
        int stp;

        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &N);

        printf("\nEnter a starting guess: ");
        scanf("%lf", &guess);

        printf("The square root of %lf is %lf\n\n", N, sqrt(N));

        return (0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon you say you have the code; that’s good. You should show it to us so we can help you. Create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and include it in your question.

Comment: hey, im sorry, im very new to all this, but i left a link to a screenshot of the code in question. Thanks. and ill look more into how to properly post.

Comment: Don’t leave screenshots of code. Those really annoy the locals here on SO. We want your code in your question so we can copy and compile it and see the problems out see — hence the demand for an MCVE. Copy’n’paste your code into the edit box, making sure you aren’t using tabs, then select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it as code.  Make sure it looks good.

Comment: my bad, i updated it, and the while loop should go after the last printf statement

Comment: Better.  Please read about the MCVE, though.  One part of the requirement is a statement of the problem — more specific than "it doesn't work".  Another part is a statement of the input, the actual output you get, and the output you expect from it.   At the moment, your code is not doing anything Babylonian — and you've not included a link to where the Babylonian algorithm can be found.  You're just using the standard library square root function.  So, you've not yet shown anything that you've tried beyond the the inputs.  Note that `stp` is an unused variable (and uninitialized too).

Comment: One step with the inputs is to echo the inputs so that you know the program got what you expected it to get.  Many a problem can be headed off by spotting that the program didn't get the input you thought it got. You should also test that the `scanf()` calls succeeded — you may get gibberish to work with if you don't. You also need to show how you do the computation using the Babylonian algorithm. (I know Newton-Raphson as an algorithm, aka divide-and-average. Yes, I can search on Google. I shouldn't have to in order to answer your question. It's in your interest to make it easy to be helped.)

Comment: i updated the explanation.

Comment: OK. It looks like the Babylonians used the Newton-Raphson technique. Now, where’s your code implementing the algorithm?

Comment: That is the part i need help with. i know i need to use a while loop, but other than that i do not know where to go. that is why i came here.

Comment: You should be able to write a loop that keeps track of how many times you’ve executed it.  You’ve got a formula which tells you how to calculate the next guess given the current guess and the number you’re trying to calculate the square root of. You just need a condition that tells you when the current guess is close enough to the correct value. How would you know that?  Would it work with the square root of 1.2345E+78?  With 1.2345E-69?  What do you need to change in your printing to handle the full range of cakes sensibly?